# How do I split list of dict in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
lis_dict = [
   {item: "some item"}, 
   {quantity: 2}, 
   {id: 10}, 
   {quantity: 2}, 
   {id: 11}, 
   {quantity: 2}, 
   {quantity: 2}, 
   {id: 12}
]
```

I have above list of `dict`, which I would like to split into a sub-list.

```
result  = [
   [{item: "some item"}, {quantity: 2}, {id: 10}],
   [{quantity: 2}, {id: 11}],
   [{quantity: 2}, {quantity: 2}, {id: 12}]
]
```

Comment: What is the source of this list of dicts?

Comment: Can you please correct you code. Your given list of dictionaries is not **valid** python syntax.

Comment: Can you also explain, by what criteria you want to split the list.

Comment: I want to split on id.

Comment: @Vishnu - Is 'ID' always preceded by 'quantity'? Does {item: 'some_item'} only come first time? Please provide more clarity on this question

Comment: @sharath you are right

Comment: Assuming your dict keys are strings, I don't see why you would be using one dict for every key-value pair. Maybe a dict format such as ```{"item": "some item", "quantity": 2, "id": 12}``` and storing a list of such dicts in ```lis_dict``` would work better for your case.

Comment: Each id is associated with preceeding quantity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question asks to split the list by "id" into a nested list.

Input:

```
lis_dict
[{'item': 'some item'},
 {'quantity': 2},
 {'id': 10},
 {'quantity': 2},
 {'id': 11},
 {'quantity': 2},
 {'quantity': 2},
 {'id': 12}]
```

Code:

```
result = []
s = 0
for i,j in enumerate(lis_dict):
    if ("id" in j.keys()):
        result.append(lis_dict[s:i+1])
        s = i+1
```

Prints:

```
[[{'item': 'some item'}, {'quantity': 2}, {'id': 10}],
 [{'quantity': 2}, {'id': 11}],
 [{'quantity': 2}, {'quantity': 2}, {'id': 12}]]
```

Comment: @kalakota vishnu is this what you would expect?

Comment: this works, thanks.
how can add item in each list. example
```[[{'item': 'some item'}, {'quantity': 2}, {'id': 10}],
 [{'item': 'some item'}, {'quantity': 2}, {'id': 11}],
 [{'item': 'some item'}, {'quantity': 2}, {'quantity': 2}, {'id': 12}]]```

Comment: or something like this 
```[[{'item': 'some item', 'quantity': 2, 'id': 10}],
 [{'item': 'some item', 'quantity': 2, 'id': 11}],
 [{'item': 'some item', 'quantity': 2, 'id': 12}]]```

Answer (score 0):

A more general approach might be the following (in which you could add more dictionaries in a sublist):

```
lis_dict = [{'item': 'some item'},
 {'quantity': 2},
 {'id': 10},
 {'quantity': 2},
 {'item': 'some item'},
 {'id': 11},
 {'quantity': 2},
 {'quantity': 2},
 {'id': 12}]

result = []
sublist = []
for d in lis_dict:
    sublist.append(d)
    if d.get("id"):
        result.append(sublist)
        sublist = []

print(result)

# [[{'item': 'some item'}, {'quantity': 2}, {'id': 10}], [{'quantity': 2}, 
# {'item': 'some item'}, {'id': 11}], [{'quantity': 2}, {'quantity': 2}, {'id': 12}]]
```